# Dotnet Listening to HTTPS port of ASP.net (port = 5001)

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-ec2, apache2, ubuntu-16.04, systemd

I have build a asp.net core web project on a Ubuntu EC2 instance of Amazon. Using Systemd and apache2 i ran he application and i was able to access the website on HTTP(port 80) but when i tried to access it on HTTPS it opened the default apache2 page. my question is how to set or what setting have i got wrong in my kestrel service since dotnet is not listening on https port of asp.net?

Within the kestrel service i tried to set the environment variable to listen to https port of aspnet (port 5001), but after changing this dotnet stopped listening to http(port 5000) as well. I don't know if i am heading in the right direction since this is my first time trying this is there any solution you thing might work?

i know i can redirect HTTPS request to HTTP and work that but i have another application which doesn't work using this method. I have to run my .net core project on https.

My kestrel file after i tried to listen to https

[Unit]

Description=Example ASP .NET Web Application running on Ubuntu 16.04
[Service]

WorkingDirectory=/var/scms

ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/scms/scms.dll

Restart=always

RestartSec=10

SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-demo

User=www-data

Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

Environment=ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORT=5000

Environment=ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=5001

Environment=ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://localhost:5000;https://localhost:5001

[Install]

WantedBy=multi-user.target

Comment: Normal web servers only acts as reverse proxy to kestrel server. You can bind any port for that. Have you checked required ports are free or not?

Comment: I did check if the port was free and yes it was free

Comment: See as i told earlier , configure apache to use https instead of http. And internally within the network(i consider it trusted) to be http (kestrel) . This way the outside facing world will be secure communication. And inside communication in trusted  network is http.

Comment: If you want kestrel connection must have secure connection please visit the microsoft pages on securing kestrel with HTTPS or HSTS.

Comment: Were you able to fix it?